# Running a map in Dash dashboard

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have written some code that returns the position of the International Space Station (ISS) on a map and also calculates the next time the ISS will be over the user's location based on the latitude and longitude they enter. Ideally, I would like to have the map run through a Dash dashboard but I am not sure how I would set this up. I have never used Dash before and from the tutorials I have seen, it seems that the data is being drawn from a spreadsheet or the like. Is it possible to have my own code for the map run in a Dash dashboard? If so any resources or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Below is my code for reference.

```
import ipyleaflet
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipyleaflet import Map, Marker, basemaps, basemap_to_tiles, AwesomeIcon, Popup
from ipywidgets import HTML, interact
import json
import urllib.request
import time
import datetime
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
result = json.loads(response.read())

location = result['iss_position']
lat_iss = float(location['latitude'])
lon_iss = float(location['longitude'])

center = [lat_iss, lon_iss] # The centre of the map will be the latitude and longtitude of the ISS
zoom = 1.5
m = Map(basemap=basemaps.Esri.WorldImagery, center=center, zoom=zoom, close_popup_on_click=False)

icon1 = AwesomeIcon(name='space-shuttle', marker_color='blue', icon_color='white', spin=False)
marker = Marker(icon=icon1, location=(lat_iss, lon_iss), draggable=False) # Add a marker at the current location of the ISS that cannot be moved
m.add_layer(marker)

user_lat = input('What is your latitude? Remember to include minus sign if the latitude is south! ')
user_lon = input('What is your longitude?  Remember to include a minus sign if the longitude is west! ')
user_location = [user_lat, user_lon]

url ='http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json'
url = url + '?lat=' + str(user_lat) + '&lon=' + str(user_lon) #The URL requires inputs for lat and lon. The users location are the inputs here.
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
result = json.loads(response.read())

over = (result['response'][1]['risetime'])
date_time = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(over).strftime('%d-%m-%Y at %H:%M:%S') #These place holders define the format of the displayed date and time.
print('The ISS will pass over you on the', date_time)

icon2 = AwesomeIcon(name='user', marker_color='lightred', icon_color='white', spin=False)
marker2 = Marker(icon=icon2, location=user_location, draggable=False) #Add  marker at the current location of the ISS that cannot be moved
m.add_layer(marker2) # Add layer that includes the users position
message1 = HTML()
message1.value = str(date_time)
popup = Popup(location=user_location, child=message1, close_button=True, auto_close=False, close_on_escape_key=False)
m.add_layer(popup) # Add layer that includes the popup message at the users location.

print('Current position of the International Space Station:')
print('Latitude of the ISS: ',lat_iss)
print('Longitude of the ISS: ',lon_iss)

m
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Dash, you would need to rewrite your code using Dash components. For the html part, you can use [`dash_html_components`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components). For the leaflet part, you can use [`dash-leaflet`](http://dash-leaflet.herokuapp.com/). There is no limit to the data source of a Dash application, I would assume that the tutorials use spread sheet data for simplicity.